# Is there any way to generate bc1... adresses in command line Electrum?

Tags: address-generation, bech32-address, command-line-options, electrum-console

I can create standard or segwit wallet. But no matter which one I created the only addresses I get is 1....

For example:

```
$ electrum createnewaddress
1FeE4ZGaSM38f6TxKzKMbCNjwbne6oLQPt
```

Is there way to create bc1... adresses using command line Electrum?

Thank you

Comment: Which version of Electrum are you using? What does the output of `electrum help createnewaddress` say?